# UIPageViewController alternative with standard slide transition animation for iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, transition, uipageviewcontroller

I'm making an app for iOS 5 which displays one UIViewController at a time with no navigation bar.

UIPageViewController is almost perfect for what I want to achieve except it only provides the page curl transition animation for iOS 5.

I found an alternative but it's a bit of a hack. I created a UINavigationController and set the navigation bar to hidden.

When navigating forward I call

```
[navigationController setViewControllers:@[newVC] animated:YES];
```

And when navigating back I call

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[prevVC, currentVC] animated:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This hack seems to work and gives me the exact transition I want, but there has to be a better way.

I'm thinking another alternative will be to use UIView animation blocks. But that will require a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I should be able to achieve what I'm after using these two functions in UIViewController:

```
addChildViewController:
```

and

```
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

These functions became available in iOS 5. I should have properly read through all the new iOS 5 features first.

Comment: There are many issues with UIPageViewController scroll style animation, it crashes in many cases and also has some internal caching issue that stops it from updating UI properly.
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21463024/844295
and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14863241/844295