# Changing UIPageViewController's page programmatically doesn't update the UIPageControl

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

In my custom `UIPageViewController` class:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.model = [[BSTCMWelcomingPageViewModel alloc] init];
        self.dataSource = self.model;
        self.delegate = self;

        self.pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I programmatically set the current `ViewController` when a button is hit:

```
- (void)scrollToNext
{
    UIViewController *current = self.viewControllers[0];
    NSInteger currentIndex = [self.model indexForViewController:current];
    UIViewController *nextController = [self.model viewControllerForIndex:++currentIndex];
    if (nextController) {
        NSArray *viewControllers = @[nextController];
        // This changes the View Controller, but PageControl doesn't update
        [self setViewControllers:viewControllers
                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                        animated:YES
                      completion:nil];
        //Nothing happens!
        [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentIndex];

        //Error: _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter: Not a setter!
        [self.pageControl updateCurrentPageDisplay];
    }
}
```

If I can't do this with the `UIPageControl` that "belongs" to my `UIPageViewController` I will just try to make my own. But it would be nice if this was possible tho!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller/39190241#39190241 @Yogesh answer may be helpful

Answer (score 26, accepted):

to update your UIPageControl indicator, you need to implement one data source method of UIPageViewController (the UIPageViewControllerDataSource method) :

```
-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

This method is responsible for updating the page control indicator (when you use UIPageViewController). You only need to return the currentpage value in this method. The Method gets called by default when you use/make a call for setViewControllers on your custom UIPageViewController.

So the chunk of code that you need to write is:

```
- (void)scrollToNext
{
    UIViewController *current = self.viewControllers[0];
    NSInteger currentIndex = [self.model indexForViewController:current];
    UIViewController *nextController = [self.model viewControllerForIndex:++currentIndex];
    if (nextController) {
        NSArray *viewControllers = @[nextController];
       // This changes the View Controller and calls the presentationIndexForPageViewController datasource method
       [self setViewControllers:viewControllers
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:YES
                  completion:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return currentIndex;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem. :)

Comment: How would this work? Is currentIndex an instance var, and if so why are you declaring it inside scrollToNext?

Comment: Note: it is important to update currentIndex BEFORE calling setViewController: ... Doing it the other way around wasn't working for me

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it helps me a code in Swift 3.0

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in accepted answer, you need to implement

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

But for me it was enough to use it like this:

**Objective-C:**

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return [self.controllers indexOfObject:[pageViewController.viewControllers firstObject]];
}
```

**Swift 3+:**

```
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let index = viewControllers?.index(of: (pageViewController.viewControllers?.first)!) else { return 0 }
        return index
}
```

Without the need to remember the current index. Where `self.controllers` is an `NSArray` of `UIViewControllers` displayed in given `UIPageViewController`. I'm not sure how exactly your `BSTCMWelcomingPageViewModel` works, but it should be easy to adjust.

Comment: This is the simplest, easiest solution. Included a Xamarin solution below.

Answer (score 2):

## Xamarin/C# Solution

I had this problem in Xamarin, here is my version of @micromanc3r's solution:

```
public class PageViewControllerDataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    UIViewController[] pages;

    public PageViewControllerDataSource(UIViewController[] pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
```

...

```
    public override nint GetPresentationIndex(UIPageViewController pageViewController)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(pages, pageViewController.ViewControllers[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4.2**

```
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let currentController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first else { 
     return 0 }
    guard let index = viewControllerList.index(of: currentController) else { return 0 }
    return index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented, transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` and navigation orientation is `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal`. Both methods are called in response to a `setViewControllers:...` call, but the presentation index is updated automatically in the case of gesture-driven navigation.

- `(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`: The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
- `(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`: The selected item reflected in the page indicator.

The answer above, given by aansul, works.

Note : Don't forget to set the pageViewController's Transition style to Scroll instead of Page Curl. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ViewController.h File

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface ViewScreen : UIViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)Startwalkthrough:(id)sender;

@property(strong, nonatomic)UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray * pageTitles;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray * pageImages;

@end

// ViewController.m File
#import "ViewScreen.h"

@interface ViewScreen ()

@end

@implementation ViewScreen

@synthesize pageTitles,pageImages;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    pageTitles =@[@"dianna",@"images",@"image",@"i1",@"hulk1",@"assasins"];
    pageImages =@[@"dianna",@"images",@"image",@"i1",@"hulk1",@"assasins"];

    self.pageViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource=self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray * viewController =@[startingViewController];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewController direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}

-(IBAction)Startwalkthrough:(id)sender
{
    PageContentViewController * startingViewController =[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray * viewControllers =@[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titletext = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}


#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index =((PageContentViewController *) viewController).pageIndex;
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    if (index ==[self.pageTitles count]) {
        return  nil;

}
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{
    return  [self.pageTitles count];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return  0;
}
@end


// Second File

PageViewController.h File 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PageContentViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *txtLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;

@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property  NSString *titletext;
@property NSString * imageFile;
@end


// SecondFile.M File
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface PageContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageContentViewController



-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self =[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //
    }
    return  self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.backgroundImageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.txtLabel.text =self.titletext;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the currentIndex BEFORE you call setViewControllers