# Convert Obj C code to Swift weak self

Tags: objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller, weak-references, self-reference

I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633059/uipageviewcontroller-how-do-i-correctly-jump-to-a-specific-page-without-messing) but I'm having difficulty to convert the

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

to Swift. Is there a way for me to convert the following code into Swift? I'm stucked convert to Swift even after reading the material said that [unowned self] or [weak self].

```
        __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        UIViewController *controller = [self.gamingPageViewController viewControllerAtIndex:index];
        [self.gamingPageViewController setViewControllers:@[controller]
        direction:(self.gamingPageIndex<index)?UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
        animated:NO
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // Method to not mess up view order in pageview            
        UIPageViewController* pvcs = weakSelf.gamingPageViewController;
        if (!pvcs) return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [pvcs setViewControllers:@[controller]
        direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
        animated:NO completion:nil];
        });

        }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift you don't need to declare a `weakSelf` variable outside the closure.

Just define your completion block as follows:

```
{ [weak self] (finished) -> () in ... }
```

and then use `self?` inside the block, in case it may be `nil`.

If `self` cannot be `nil`, you may need to use `[unowned self]` instead of `[weak self]`.